# javascript - Hide Options from Multiple Selection Box when an option from another select is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help. So what I want to do is when a user select an option from one select, automatically hide an option from another multiple select.

Example:
if a user choose Car from `select A`, I want the car option from the `select B` to be automatically removed or hidden.

**select A:**

```
<select name="my_option_one" required id="id_my_option_one">
    <option value="" selected>Choose..</option>
    <option value="C">Car</option>
    <option value="H">House</option>
    <option value="A">Airplane</option>
</select>
```

**Select B:**

```
<select name="my_option_two"  id="id_my_option_two" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="C">Car</option>
    <option value="H">House</option>
    <option value="A">Airplane</option>
</select>
```

This is what I have tried but none of it worked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_my_option_one").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === 'C') {
            $("#id_my_option_two option[value='C']").options[0].remove();
            $('select[name=my_option_two] option:eq(1)').hide();
            $("#id_my_option_two option[value=" + 'C' + "]").hide();
            $("#id_my_option_two option[value='C']").attr('disabled','disabled').hide(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I added the codes above. Hope you might help

Comment: Please, in the future, add your code in a code snippet ( `<>` icon in the toolbar ) just like i did in my answer. Otherwise it's very hard to read. Also, i assume that your options have the same values. ( Car has value C in both selects ). If not, tell me and i'll change the answer

Comment: Thank you  @MihaiT, it works. I will add my code in a code snippet next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function my_optionsChange() {
  $("#id_my_options_two option").show(); //.css("display", "block");
  $("#id_my_options_two option[value='" + $("#id_my_options").val() + "']").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="my_options" required id="id_my_options" onchange="my_optionsChange()">
    <option value="" selected>Choose..</option>
    <option value="C">Car</option>
    <option value="H">House</option>
    <option value="A">Airplane</option>
</select>

<select name="my_options_two"  id="id_my_options_two" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="C">Car</option>
    <option value="H">House</option>
    <option value="A">Airplane</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made an example which is longer because it's split into parts so you understand better what is going on.

I tried to name the variables so that it's clear what they are, but if you have any questions, please ask in the comments.

Let me know if this works for you.

```js
const firstSelect = $('#id_my_options')
const secondSelect = $('#id_my_options_two')

firstSelect.on('change',function() {
  const selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
  const selectedValue = selected.val()
  const secondOptions = secondSelect.children();
  secondOptions.each(function() {
     const secondValue = $(this).val()
     secondValue === selectedValue ?  $(this).hide() :  $(this).show()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="my_options" required id="id_my_options">
  <option value="Choose" selected>Choose..</option>
  <option value="C">Car</option>
  <option value="H">House</option>
  <option value="A">Airplane</option>
</select>
<select name="my_options_two" id="id_my_options_two" multiple="multiple"> 
  <option value="C">Car</option> 
  <option value="H">House</option> 
  <option value="A">Airplane</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name="my_options"  id="firstblock" onchange="disable(2,this.value);">
    <option value="" selected>Choose..</option>
    <option value="C">Car</option>
    <option value="H">House</option>
    <option value="A">Airplane</option>
</select>
<select name="my_options"  id="secondblock" onchange="disable(1,this.value);">
    <option value="" selected>Choose..</option>
    <option value="C">Car</option>
    <option value="H">House</option>
    <option value="A">Airplane</option>
</select>

<script>

   function disable(needtoblock,val){
   console.log(needtoblock+" "+val);
    if(val != ""){

        if(needtoblock == 1){
         $("#firstblock option[value='"+val+"']").prop('disabled', true);
        }else if(needtoblock == 2){
         $("#secondblock option[value='"+val+"']").prop('disabled', true);
        }else{

        }
    }else{
             $("#secondblock option").prop('disabled', false);
             $("#firstblock option").prop('disabled', false);
    }
   }
</script>
```

This is how code could look, definetly you need to update and make it suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is a bit late, but maybe it is of interest to someone out there. I understood the demand of OP so, that the hiding of options was to be done in **any direction**, or potentially spanning over **multiple selector boxes**. The following script will do exactly that: if you **select an option** in one selector it will go through the other selectors of the defined group `$grp` (by doing `$grp.not(this).each((i,trg)=> ...)`) and will **hide/show all options** there, depending of whether thay have been selected elsewhere already.

The `$(to).toggle(...)` method sets the visibility of each option (`to`) within `trg`, based on the existence of selected options with the same value in the sibling selectors of `trg` (again, limited to the current group `$grp`).

Maybe the script is a little *too condensed* for easy reading but it shows how much you can achieve with very little code when you use the power of jQuery.

```js
const $grp=$('select[id^=id_my_options]') // define the selector group
$grp.on('change',function(ev){  // bind the change event ...
 $grp.not(this).each((i,trg)=>  // work on each sibling-selector (trg) of clicked 
                                // selector (this), but only within jquery 
                                // selection $grp
  $('option[value!=""]',trg).each((j,to)=>  // for all options of sibling-selectors of 
                                // trg (within jquery selection $grp):  
   $(to).toggle($grp.not(trg).find('option[value='+to.value+']:selected').length==0))
                                // toggle the visibiltiy of that option
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="my_options" required id="id_my_options">
  <option value="" selected>Choose..</option>
  <option value="C">Car</option>
  <option value="H">House</option>
  <option value="A">Airplane</option>
</select>

<select name="my_options_two"  id="id_my_options_two" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="C">Car2</option>
  <option value="H">House2</option>
  <option value="A">Airplane2</option>
</select>

<select name="my_options_three"  id="id_my_options_three" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="O">yet another option</option>
  <option value="C">Car3</option>
  <option value="H">House3</option>
  <option value="A">Airplane3</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<select name="my_options_four"  id="id_your_options_four" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="O">and some unrelated options</option>
  <option value="C">Car3</option>
  <option value="H">House3</option>
  <option value="A">Airplane3</option>
</select>
```